# Android Saturation filter Matrix

Tags: android, filter, matrix, imagefilter

I have written following matrix for Saturation but it is not giving proper results.Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

```
   ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(saturationFilter(0.3f));
   ColorMatrixColorFilter matrix = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);

    public static float[] saturationFilter(float x){

    float lumR = 0.3086f;
    float lumG = 0.6094f;
    float lumB = 0.0820f;
    float matrix[] = {lumR*(1-x)+x,lumG*(1-x),lumB*(1-x), 0, 0, 0,0,
                      lumR*(1-x)+x,lumG*(1-x),lumB*(1-x), 0, 0, 0,0,
                      lumR*(1-x)+x,lumG*(1-x),lumB*(1-x), 0, 0, 0,0,
                      0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                      0f ,0f, 0f, 0f ,1f};

    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the above function by writing the matrix correctly since i was increasing red channel in all the cases that was wrong.This is working fine.

```
   public static float[] saturationFilter(float saturation){

    float p_val = cleanValue(saturation,100);
    float x = 1+((p_val > 0) ? 3*p_val/100 : p_val/100);
    float lumR = 0.3086f;
    float lumG = 0.6094f;
    float lumB = 0.0820f;
    float matrix[] = {lumR*(1-x)+x, lumG*(1-x),  lumB*(1-x), 0, 0, 
                      lumR*(1-x),   lumG*(1-x)+x, lumB*(1-x), 0, 0,
                      lumR*(1-x),   lumG*(1-x),   lumB*(1-x)+x, 0, 0,
                      0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                      0f ,0f, 0f, 0f ,1f};

    return matrix;
   }

     private static float cleanValue(float p_val, float p_limit){
         return Math.min(p_limit, Math.max(-p_limit, p_val));
}
```

Comment: The matrix should be 4x5, not 5x5. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html